# How to override global parameter of javascript?

Tags: javascript, django, docker

#### Background:

I have web project written in django(python), record some global settings in `settings.py`

**settings.py**

```
EXTERNAL_SERVICE_IP = 10.192.225.30
```

When I deliver this project to users, they may need to change this `EXTERNAL_SERVICE_IP`, as they deploy the service on different IP.

Normally, they can modify this **settings.py**, but when I deliver this project using `docker`, it is not so convenient. So changed the `settings.py`.

```
EXTERNAL_SERVICE_IP = os.environ.get('EXTERNAL_SREVICE_IP')
```

Then, when start the container, user can use `-e` to pass their external service ip to python.

#### Question:

Now, same scenario happened in javascript part. I have a `settings.js`

**settings.js**

```
const SERVICE_API = "http://10.192.225.18:8090/xxx/"
```

The web's ui part will let browser to use this to launch a ajax call in javascript, of course, we use `jsonp`, so no `cross-origin` issue.

So, if the project also in docker container, what's the best way for user to override this `SERVICE_API` in javascript? I don't want user to `docker exec` to change this file, not out-of-box for user.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use system variables using `process.env.EXTERNAL_SREVICE_IP`

```
const SERVICE_API = `http://${process.env.EXTERNAL_SREVICE_IP}:8090/xxx/`;
```

Comment: A little curious: the settings.js will be run on browser side, how it can work? It's not a nodejs application. Anyway, I will give it a try.

Comment: Right, system variables are available only on the server side. You can prepare this file during the build process.

Comment: Thanks, I afford the image on docker hub, so I do not want user to participate in this build process, just something out-of-box use will be what I look for, any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve your goal by modifying package.json, for example:

```
{
  config: {
    "api": "http://10.192.225.18:8090/xxx/"
  }
}
```

next, you can get url：

```
process.env.npm_package_config_api
```

Comment: This is a pure javascript file used by a html with something like `<script>.../settings.js</script>`? How to add your answer to my code?